Oscilloscope makes board glitch out?
I am baffled.  Well and truly flummoxed.  I was testing some boards, because a particular receiver component on them had been substituted for one whose readings were really noisy.  There was one board I was sorta using as a comparison board, so I'd tested it quite a few times and checked it with the oscilloscope, etc.  Then suddenly I started getting weird errors on a port that had been working fine.  It even disconnected from my debug probe.  THEN I realized this was only happening when I connected my oscilloscope to one of the pins.  Further testing revealed that this happened even when my oscilloscope wasn't connected, and it happened with all three oscilloscope probes I tried.  I tested the resistance (~infinite) and capacitance (0.2nF) on one of them, and both those numbers seem like they couldn't reasonably be affecting things - the pin in question was the signal out pin of a fiber optic receiver; the component is powered, it's a 3v3 signal, nothing especially sensitive.  I just tested another of the same component on the same board, and it gives similar behavior.  And again, I'm pretty sure it used to be fine!  It seemed like a pretty abrupt change.  Also, I THINK I saw it happen on other circuits, but now it's not happening anymore, so...guess I'll chalk that up to faulty memory.  But to top it off, I'm pretty convinced I once connected ONLY the ground clip of the oscilloscope to the ground wire, and at that moment the board disconnected from the debug probe!  The oscilloscope wasn't connected to anything else; it's battery-powered!  (I again think the board in question that time was a different board...but it MIGHT have still been the one currently displaying weird behavior.)
What on earth could be happening here?  How is an oscilloscope lead, any of three tested, not necessarily even connected to the oscilloscope, causing errors in a 3v3 logic line?
I did just figure out that the weirdness only happens when I connect the oscilloscope probe to one of the ORIGINAL components, and not the substitutes.  (The original component was a ZGY135/T9(PLR).)  Maybe it's amplifying and retaining tiny noises or something???  After I remove the probe, it continues giving errors until I send it an optical signal, then it quiets down.  Still, though!  I don't understand how an oscilloscope probe, (presumably) designed not to affect a system, would cause such problems in a system that shouldn't be particularly susceptible to small noise.  Nor do I know why it seems to have only begun doing this an hour ago.  Nor do I know how that component (or original noise) would cause the microcontroller to disconnect from the debug probe, though I consider that a lesser mystery subsequent to the first.

Is it x1 probe or x10 probe? x1 causes quite a bit of capacitive loading and will wreck fast signals.

So you are using a standard TOSLINK receiver? For digital SPDIF audio or for some other purpose? What signal or protocol? Does the noise output happen only when it receives no light pulses? Please show schematics how you use the receiver.

It's pretty common that something does not work except when oscilloscope is connected, or also, something works until an oscilloscope is connected.
You are measuring an output of a fiber optic receiver - these usually go from hundreds of kilobits to gigabits.
Depending on the probe and the probe setting between 1x and 10x modes, the capacitance of the coaxial cable can be significant.
The probe may slow down rise and fall times, and depending on the output impedance, add a delay or attenuate the signal, because it can be thought as an RC filter.
And if the link has multiple lanes in parallel, delaying one data lane too much compared to other data lanes or a clock lane, it might stop the data reception from working.
Also you are using cheap TOSLINK modules. They simply convert light to voltage. They need a signal to do that well. Without a signal, they output anything. If enough light from room fluorescent lights leak into the photodiode, you might even see the fluorescent light flicker frequency as a square wave (double the mains frequency).
The modules may also be sensitive to what data you send, and not all TOSLINK recivers handle too slow signals well.
Also the data sheet says to put enough bypass capacitance at the module. And even for 5V supply, a capacitor is needed for data output too. It might be that adding the scope probe to data line adds just enough capacitance that the chip supply sags a bit when the output toggles, so it then affects the internal circuitry via the supply to switch state again.

Hmm.  My multimeter reads 0.2nF on the probe, but maybe it's higher at higher frequencies?  Plausible enough, I suppose; thanks
